# Sub setting large data into smaller data set in R

Tags: r, subset

I have two data sets, one data set A with 700 rows and columns a,b,c,d and data B with 3000 rows, with same variables as data A , a,b,c,d. I want to create a scatter plot for dataset A and B with variables a. But since data set B is massively larger then A it overpowers dataset B, hence I want to reduce the size of the dataset B and only take rows from set B which are compatible in numbers with data set A  to create a scatter plot (and also statistically justifiable). what technique would be ideal to create another data set C which is subset of data set B . I have used random sampling but it gives me different spread of scatter plot everytime i run my model in R

Comment: If random sampling makes sense, but you want the same random sample each time you run your model, you can set a seed using `set.seed(508)` (or whatever value you like). To offer alternative ways of under sampling dataset B, we'd need to see samples of the data frames and maybe an explanation of what makes only some rows compatible.

Comment: How are you doing a scatter plot with a single variable (a)? If your original question has a typo and you are actually plotting two variables, then I don't see the justification for omitting any of the data in set B. If the concern is that *graphically* the larger number of points in B makes it hard to see those of A, you might instead want to use a 2D density/contour plot, e.g. `geom_density_2d`.

Comment: Thanks @Seth, very helpful suggestion. I will incorporate the suggestion in  my analysis . My two data sets are two categories of university set A is selective while  set B is not. the variables a is the overall student performance for ug degree, b is the location c is the total number of people from within the area and d is the predictive value (I applied  multi variable regression here on both the dataset). Now I want to compare the student performance comparing selective and non selective unis. And hence when i subset my dataset i don't want results to be biased.

Comment: Hi @C.Murtaugh, please see my above comment

Comment: Maybe this gets more/better help on https://stats.stackexchange.com since it's mostly about sampling.